# PostgreSQL issue: could not access file "$libdir/plpgsql": No such file or directory

Tags: postgresql

I get this exception in PostgreSQL:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: could not access file "$libdir/plpgsql": No such file or directory
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1721)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1489)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:193)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.execute(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:452)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeWithFlags(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:337)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeQuery(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:236)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingStatement.executeQuery(DelegatingStatement.java:205)
```

I searched a lot and most solution points to a wrong installation. But this is my test db which has been running without issues for a long time. Also inserts are working. Issue occurs only on select queries.

Comment: What operating system is your test db on?

Answer (score 7):

Apparently, you moved your PostgreSQL lib directory out of place.  To confirm this, try the following in psql:

```
> SET client_encoding TO iso88591;
ERROR:  could not access file "$libdir/utf8_and_iso8859_1": No such file or directory
```

If you get an error message like this, then my theory is correct.  You'll need to find out where those files ended up, or you can reinstall PostgreSQL to restore them.

To find out what `$libdir` is referring to, run the following command:

```sh
pg_config --pkglibdir
```

For me, this produces:

```
/usr/lib/postgresql
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. Will be checking this on Monday. But if as you said, lib directory is having an issue, then the inserts should also fail, right? As i mentioned in my first post, inserts are working but selects are failing.                                          OS is CentOS 5X

Comment: There were issues in the db installation. We have moved this to a separate box . Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem:  the other postgres server instance (8.4) was interfering with the 9.1 one; when the 8.4 instance is removed it works.

Answer (score 0):

the other instance can sometimes be removed from the system while still running (e.g. you do a gentoo update and a depclean without stopping and migrating your data). so the error seems particularly mysterious.

the solution is usually going to be doing a slot install/eselect of the old version (in gentoo terms, or simply downgrading on other distros), running its pg_dumpall, and then uninstalling/reinstalling the new version and importing the data.

this worked pretty painlessly for me

Comment: Gentoo slotting was exactly my problem; thanks.  Somehow the currently-running version was removed when a higher version (slot) was installed.  Too bad someone else downvoted your answer -- probably due to ignorance about Gentoo.  I gave you a counterbalancing upvote.